# How can I stop Windows asking me to authenticate on actions requiring admin privileges on a newly created admin account?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, administrator

I created a new Windows user account on my laptop, with the administrator account type. On the new account, I have to go through with this authentication every time I have to do something requiring administrator privileges:

[image: screenshot]

This was not the case on the original account.

Even worse, the option to enter my PIN is hidden behind a drawer. By default, it asks me to authenticate using the password for the original account. I have to go click "More Options" before I can use the PIN or password for my own account.

##### How can I make it so that, like the old account, all I'm asked to do is click "Yes" when doing something requiring administrator privileges?

Comment: Was your other account by chance the built-in Administrator account?

Comment: What account did you use when creating the new one, and how exactly did you create it?

Comment: @Ramhound yes..

Comment: @harrymc "Add, edit, or remove other users" in Start

Comment: Of what groups is it a member?

Comment: @harrymc I'm going to assume you're asking what settings group the "Add, edit, or remove other users" screen is part of: Settings > Accounts > Family & other users

Comment: @HyperboLee - **What you want is impossible.** The behavior of the built-in Administrator account, when it comes to UAC, is unique and cannot be duplicated

Comment: @Ramhound No...? I've used PCs before with multiple admin users, none of which are required to authenticate themselves (only asked to click Yes/No)

Comment: Did those machines even have UAC enabled?

Comment: @Ramhound ...yes? The "Yes/No" screen I keep talking about *is* UAC

Comment: Is you account in Administrators local group or not? Are you prompted  to enter password for different user or the sinned in user? It looks to me it is two different accounts. UAC will prompt you Yes/No conformation for you singin on account only.